# Why is this win32 edit control in the mdi client area not working?

Tags: winapi, controls, mdi

I have an Win32 C++ MDI form with a toolbar at the top, a statusbar at the bottom and an edit control sitting on top of the statusbar, with the rest of the client area clear for child windows.

Here's the code to create the edit control:

```
HFONT hfDefault;
HWND hEdit;

TCHAR lpszSometext[] = L"This is the first line in this edit control "
L"This is the second line in this edit control "
L"This is the third line in this edit control ";

hEdit = CreateWindowEx(
WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT",
NULL,
WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
0, 0, 0, 0,
hWnd,
(HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT,
GetModuleHandle(NULL),
NULL);

if (hEdit == NULL)
    MessageBox(hWnd, L"Could not create edit control.", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

SendMessage(hEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)lpszSometext);

hfDefault = (HFONT)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
SendMessage(hEdit, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfDefault, MAKELPARAM(FALSE, 0));
```

And this is the code to resize the toolbar, statusbar and edit control in WM_SIZE of the main window callback;

```
HWND hToolbar, hStatusbar, hEdit, hMDI;
RECT rcToolbar, rcStatusbar, rcClient;
int iToolbarHeight, iStatusbarHeight, iEditHeight, iMDIHeight;

iEditHeight = 60;

hToolbar = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_MAIN_TOOL);
SendMessage(hToolbar, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);

hStatusbar = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_MAIN_STATUS);
SendMessage(hStatusbar, WM_SIZE, 0, 0);

GetWindowRect(hToolbar, &rcToolbar);
iToolbarHeight = rcToolbar.bottom - rcToolbar.top;

GetWindowRect(hStatusbar, &rcStatusbar);
iStatusbarHeight = rcStatusbar.bottom - rcStatusbar.top;

GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);
iMDIHeight = rcClient.bottom - iToolbarHeight - iStatusbarHeight -        iEditHeight;

hEdit = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_MAIN_EDIT);
SetWindowPos(hEdit, NULL, 0, rcClient.bottom - iStatusbarHeight - iEditHeight, rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom - iStatusbarHeight, SWP_NOZORDER);

hMDI = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_MAIN_MDI);
SetWindowPos(hMDI, NULL, 0, iToolbarHeight, rcClient.right, iMDIHeight, SWP_NOZORDER);
```

All three controls are created the same way with CreateWindowEx(), however the text placed in the edit control at creation is a no-show and the edit control makes hideous artifacts on the MDI clint window whenever the main form is resized, as if the edit control is trying to snap to the bottom of the toolbar.

Comment: It's really impossible to tell just from this snippet. But when you're sizing the edit control, you're not actually using `iEditHeight` to set the height. Perhaps it's ending up the wrong size and overlapping other controls?

Answer (score 0):

This a demo @A. Marchi. Refer Link: [MDI child window and status bar C win32 API [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235797/mdi-child-window-and-status-bar-c-win32-api)

I'm trying to combine your code with demo and reproduce your problem.

But there's no need for the problems you described in the code I tried, but you can refer to this demo to find problems in your code.

**ep:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h> //per SBARS_SIZEGRIP e STATUSCLASSNAME

#define IDM_OPEN        100
#define IDM_EXIT        101
#define IDM_ABOUT       102
#define IDC_STATUSBAR   103
#define IDM_ARRANGE     104
#define IDM_CASCADE     105
#define IDM_TILE        106
#define IDM_CLOSEALL    107
#define IDM_CLOSE       108
#define ID_CLIENTWND    109
#define IDM_FIRSTCHILD  5000
#define IDC_MAIN_EDIT 133
#define IDC_MAIN_TOOL 134

TCHAR lpszSometext[] = "This is the first line in this edit control "
"This is the second line in this edit control "
"This is the third line in this edit control ";
const char frameClass[] = "myFrameClass";
const char clientClass[] = "mdiclient"; //funziona solo con "mdiclient"
const char childClass[] = "myChildClass";

HWND hWndStatusBar = NULL;
HWND hWndClient = NULL;
HFONT hfDefault;
HWND hEdit;
HWND hToolbar;

//STEP 5 Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        //STEP 6: Create Status Bar
        hWndStatusBar = CreateWindowEx(0, STATUSCLASSNAME, NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBARS_SIZEGRIP,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            hwnd,
            (HMENU)IDC_STATUSBAR,
            (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);

        if (!hWndStatusBar) {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Failed To Create The Status Bar", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            return 0;
        }
        // Establish the number of partitions or 'parts' the status bar will 
        // have, their actual dimensions will be set in the parent window's 
        // WM_SIZE handler.
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        int nHalf = rc.right / 2;
        int nParts[4] = { nHalf, nHalf + nHalf / 3, nHalf + nHalf * 2 / 3, -1 };
        SendMessage(hWndStatusBar, SB_SETPARTS, 4, (LPARAM)&nParts);

        //crea la finestra CLIENT
        CLIENTCREATESTRUCT ccs;
        // Assign the 'Window' menu.
        ccs.hWindowMenu = GetSubMenu(GetMenu(hwnd), 1); // uno perchè così la finestra appare nel secondo menu (partendo da zero) ovvero nel menu 'Windows'
        ccs.idFirstChild = IDM_FIRSTCHILD;
        // Create the client window. (quella che contiene i child!!)
        hWndClient = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, clientClass,//FUNZIONA SOLO CON "mdiclient"
            NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_VISIBLE,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            hwnd, (HMENU)ID_CLIENTWND/*GetMenu(hwnd)*/, GetModuleHandle(NULL), &ccs);
        if (hWndClient == NULL) {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Client Window Creation Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    }
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        HWND hToolbar, hEdit, hMDI;
        RECT rcToolbar, rcClient;
        int iToolbarHeight, iEditHeight, iMDIHeight;
        iEditHeight = 60;
        hToolbar = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_TOOL);
        SendMessage(hToolbar, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
        GetWindowRect(hToolbar, &rcToolbar);
        iToolbarHeight = rcToolbar.bottom - rcToolbar.top;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcClient);
        iMDIHeight = rcClient.bottom - iToolbarHeight - iEditHeight;
        //resize the parts
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        int nHalf = rc.right / 2;
        int nParts[4] = { nHalf, nHalf + nHalf / 3, nHalf + nHalf * 2 / 3, -1 };
        SendMessage(hWndStatusBar, SB_SETPARTS, 4, (LPARAM)&nParts);
        //resize MDI
        // get client area of frame window
        RECT clientRect;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &clientRect);
        int frame_dx = clientRect.right - clientRect.left;
        int frame_dy = clientRect.bottom - clientRect.top;
        // get client area of status bar
        RECT statusRect;
        GetClientRect(hWndStatusBar, &statusRect);
        int status_dy = statusRect.bottom - statusRect.top;
        // position the MDIClient such that it doesn't overlap with status bar
        MoveWindow(hWndClient, 0, 0, frame_dx, frame_dy - status_dy, TRUE);
        //resize the statusbar
        SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_STATUSBAR), WM_SIZE, 0, 0);
        hEdit = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_EDIT);
        SetWindowPos(hEdit, NULL, 0, rcClient.bottom - iEditHeight, rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom, SWP_NOZORDER);
        hMDI = GetDlgItem(hwnd, ID_CLIENTWND);
        SetWindowPos(hMDI, NULL, 0, iToolbarHeight, rcClient.right, iMDIHeight, SWP_NOZORDER);
        return 0; //ritorna zero altrimenti la Frame Window ridisegna il MDI client spalmandolo su tutta la client area andando sopra alla status bar
    }
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDM_EXIT) DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDM_ABOUT) MessageBox(hwnd, "ABOUT premuto", "ciao", MB_OK);
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDM_OPEN) {
            //apre il file...
            MDICREATESTRUCT mdicreate = { 0 };
            mdicreate.szClass = childClass;
            mdicreate.szTitle = "class_mdichild";
            mdicreate.hOwner = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE); // <- hinstance
            mdicreate.x = CW_USEDEFAULT;
            mdicreate.y = CW_USEDEFAULT;
            mdicreate.cx = CW_USEDEFAULT;
            mdicreate.cy = CW_USEDEFAULT;
            mdicreate.style = 0;
            mdicreate.lParam = 0;
            HWND hwndChild = (HWND)SendMessage(hWndClient, WM_MDICREATE, 0, (LPARAM)(LPMDICREATESTRUCT)&mdicreate);
            if (hwndChild == NULL) {
                MessageBox(hwnd, "Impossibile creare la finestra Child", "Errore", MB_ICONERROR);
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        //return DefWindowProc(hwnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
        return DefFrameProc(hwnd, hWndClient, msg, wParam, lParam); //per tenere conto delle finestre figlie
    }
    return DefFrameProc(hwnd, hWndClient, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ChildWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_COMMAND:

        break;
        /* All other messages (a lot of them) are processed using default procedures */
    default:
        return DefMDIChildProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return DefMDIChildProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    //STEP 1: Registering Frame Class Window
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_APPWORKSPACE + 1);//(COLOR_WINDOW);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = frameClass;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Frame Window Registration Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return 0;
    }

    //la classe CLIENT non la devo registrare?

    //STEP 1.2: Registering Child Class Window
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)ChildWndProc;
    wc.hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(0, IDI_APPLICATION, IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_SHARED);
    wc.hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImage(hInstance, childClass, IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
    wc.hCursor = (HCURSOR)LoadImage(0, IDC_ARROW, IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, LR_SHARED);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);//(COLOR_WINDOW);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = childClass;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Child Window Registration Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return 0;
    }

    //STEP 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        frameClass,
        "FrameWindow",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    hEdit = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT",
        NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        hwnd,
        (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT,
        GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        NULL);
    if (hEdit == NULL)
        MessageBox(hwnd, "Could not create edit control.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

    SendMessage(hEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)lpszSometext);

    hfDefault = (HFONT)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
    SendMessage(hEdit, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfDefault, MAKELPARAM(FALSE, 0));
    hToolbar = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL,
        WS_CHILD | TBSTYLE_WRAPABLE, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_TOOL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    if (hToolbar == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Frame Window Creation Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);



    //STEP 3: Create Menu

    HMENU hMenu = CreateMenu(); //crea un menu vuoto

    HMENU hSubMenu; //variabile usata per aggiungere sottomenu ti tipo POPUP

    hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_OPEN, "&Open");
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_CLOSE, "&Close");
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_EXIT, "&Exit");
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu, "&File"); //aggiunge il sottomenu al menu

    hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_ARRANGE, "Arrange");
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_CASCADE, "Cascade");
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_TILE, "Tile");
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_CLOSEALL, "Close All");
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu, "&Windows");

    hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUT, "&About");
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu, "&Help");

    if (hMenu == NULL) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Menu Creation Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return 0;
    }

    SetMenu(hwnd, hMenu); //setta il menu sulla finestra



    //STEP 4: Message Loop
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        if (hWndClient && TranslateMDISysAccel(hWndClient, &msg)) continue; //process the predefined MDI specific accelerator keys
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

This is Result:
[image: MDI]

If you have any questions, please feel free to contact me. I'd be happy to help you solve them.

Comment: I don't know why but with this I have the same issues with the Edit control, ie: no text and artefacts in the client window when resizing. I've solved both by using MoveWindow() in WM_RESIZE for all the controls then SetWindowPosition() for the mdi client area, but I don't understand why MoveWindow() doesn't work for that. Massive thanks for the help, I'll remember you when I'm rich and famous!

Comment: @benjweston In theory, `MoveWindow` and `SetWindowsPos` have the same functions. You set the edit control in `WM_SIZE` in the bottom area, so the control does not appear in the MDI client area. At the same time, the edit control seems to work only in the bottom area (text can be added), which seems to be the system of the MDI window. Settings caused.